# Understanding Post increment concept in C

Tags: c, assembly, undefined-behavior, sequence-points

Consider code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int x=0,y=5;
    printf("x=%d,x_1=%d,sum=%d",x++,x,y+x);
    return 0;
}
```

My assumption on this code was that, x would be printed as 0 and later on postincrement x_1 would be 1 and y+x be 5+1=6

Actual result is x as 0 as expected , x_1 as 1 as expected. But y+x be 5. I am unsure why x retains its previous value though an postincrement had occured. Could you please help clarify this?
I used gcc compiler for the same.

Comment: You will never undertand code like `printf("x=%d,x_1=%d,sum=%d",x++,x,y+x);`, because there is "too much going on".  But if you break it up into three separate calls: `printf("x=%d,",x++);                                                                                                                                                                       
printf("x_1=%d,",x);                                                                                                                                                                       
printf("sum=%d\n",y+x);
` it should make sense.

Comment: @SteveSummit This is just a different trial. I know behavior would be as expected if they were written separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In

```
printf("x=%d,x_1=%d,sum=%d", x++, x, y+x);
//                           (a) (b)  (b)
```

you are both updating `x` (a) and using its value (b) in the same expression (*with no intervening sequence point*).
That's Undefined Behaviour.

Try

```
printf("x=%d,x_1=%d,sum=%d", x, x + 1, y + x + 1);
x++;
```

Comment: Please bear with me if question is absurd. Incase implementation didn't happen in a sequence, why does it give same response everytime i run the program? Doesn't it mean there's actually some sequence followed?

Comment: See https://ideone.com/avSVxI -- does not compile. The "sequence" you see is bad luck. It might change when there's a full moon, when you compile again, when your teacher is watching ... and it may even do something else entirely, like printing the lyrics of the national anthem of Spain :)

Comment: What's WHICHx in that? it's neither declared  nor initialized. 
On a fun note, "An astrologer here, say more about my future please?" :-)

Comment: I have no idea which `WHICHx` happens when you run the program (but reverse engineering might tell you what happened); it's Undefined Behaviour. That was just an attempt at explaining the behaviour you see, not the behaviour of the code in general.

Comment: I appreciate your effort on that .

Answer (score 1):

This is standard undefined behaviour, order of evalution of function arguments is non deterministic. Read [[Why are these constructs using pre and post-increment undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/why-are-these-constructs-using-pre-and-post-increment-undefined-behavior])

Comment: If you find a duplicate, please flag it as a duplicate instead of linking the dup in an answer.